# A verb that describes an action by someone who is new in town

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a verb that describes someone from the countryside (ie: new in town ) who tries to behave , dress and speak like its people to fit in and not be taken for a redneck ?

Comment: Verbs don''t describe people; verbs describe feelings, intentions, and behaviors. If it's the behavior you're asking about, there is no verb that specifically refers to that -- it's an awfully precise concept, after all. But one can certainly describe it, as you did.

Comment: we need a verb to describe these 'one word insult' trolls.

Comment: @Oldcat: Why stop there? Shouldn't there be a word for *the feeling of despair you get when reading the tenth question in one day asking for a single word to describe **almost this very feeling**, but when it's only the **ninth** one so far today*?

Comment: Actually, I've got this nagging feeling that I once knew a word for *exactly and only* the feeling you get when you sit on the lavatory seat and it's still warm from the previous occupant. I'd dearly love to know if I really did, and if so what it was.

Comment: Note that "redneck" isn't the appropriate word here (look it up).  Something like "rube" might be more neutral, but you would want to look that up also.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "_Shoeburyness_" from [The Salmon of Doubt/Meaning of Liff](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=xU3m_s5O7yMC&pg=PT28&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most apposite verb is **[acculturate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/acculturate)**, meaning "to assimilate a different culture".

You could also say that the country dweller *[conformed to](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conform) the urban lifestyle*, *[adopted](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adopt?show=0&t=1401481205) metropolitan practices*, or *[observed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/observe) citified customs*".

Here is an example:

> The arriviste from Arkansas **acculturated to** his new urban surroundings.

Answer (score 1):

You may use *[blend in](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/blend-in-blend-into-sth)*:

> He tried to **blend in** with the locals.

Comment: But can I use this verb in a sarcastic way like suppose I meet him then I say " I see that you're acclimatising " or maybe I am with a  friend and want to slag off someone else & say " hey look he's acclimatising " or is there another word which may make this outta town guy not wanted & uncomfortable ?

Comment: @Scratch2Win: In most cases it would be pretty puerile to mock someone for making the effort to [assimilate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/assimilate) into a new cultural milieu, so I think English *as a language* is probably too "grown up" to provide such a word with specifically pejorative overtones. More generally, if you feel you *must* make such an observation, you might consider ***ingratiate, insinuate, get in with, suck up to, worm into*** etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to say this.  The nice way would be to say he is trying to *fit in*.

Something that adds a little zing but isn't too bad is saying that he is *conforming*.

> •(of a person) behave according to socially acceptable conventions or
>   standards.

If the person is reluctant or was out of their realm then you can say they *gave in* or they were [acquiescent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquiesce).

> to accept, comply, or submit tacitly or passively